# Create a custom block programmatically and specify region and pages on which created block must shown on

Tags: 8, blocks

For create block programmatically I use

```
$block = BlockContent::create([
  'info' => 'block 3',
  'type' => 'basic',
  'langcode' => 'en',
  'body' => [
    'value' => '<h1>Block's body</h1>',
    'format' => 'full_html',
  ],
]);
$block->save();
```

It works good enough but is it possible also to specify region and then on which pages created block must shown on?

Comment: I think it is not possible to mention region while creating custom block. Better go to structure -> block layout-> click place block in any one of the region and assign the block once you created a custom block

Comment: If that true it's very sad becuase I need ceate many blocks and manually specify region and pages for each of them will took too much time. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: Or maybe somone knows way to do it after creating of block? I mean add some code after string  $block->save();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, at least I managed to solve this problem.

Below the full code that create block and then bind it to region and also set pages  on which created block must shown on. Maybe it can helps anyone.

```
 $block = BlockContent::create([
         'info' => 'block242',
         'type' => 'basic',
         'langcode' => 'en',
         'body' => [

          'value' => '<h1>Block's body</h1>',
            'format' => 'full_html',
           ],
          ]);


     $block->save();


       $placed_block = Block::create([
         'id' => 'block242',
            'theme' => 'scholarly',
'weight' => -7,
'status' => TRUE,
'region' => 'sidebar_second',
'plugin' => 'block_content:' . $block->uuid(),
'settings' => [],
'visibility' => [
  'request_path' => [
    'id' => 'request_path',
    'negate' => FALSE,
    'pages' => '/your_page',
  ],
],
        ]);
    $placed_block->save();
```

And of course, very very BIG thanks to user 4k4. Without his help I'd never do this.

Comment: Don't forget to 
use Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent;

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a block config entity to place a block:

```
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;

  $placed_block = Block::create([
    'id' => 'block_machine_name',
    'theme' => 'classy',
    'weight' => 0,
    'status' => TRUE,
    'region' => 'footer',
    'plugin' => 'block_content:' . $block->uuid(),
    'settings' => [],
    'visibility' => [
      'request_path' => [
        'id' => 'request_path',
        'negate' => FALSE,
        'pages' => '/path',
      ],
    ],
  ]);
  $placed_block->save();
```

Comment: Oh! Many thanks!!! I'll try it for sure but what about pages on which block must shown on? Is it possible to set it in code above?

Comment: Yes, put this in the now empty visibility array. Each visibility plugin has different parameters. Configure one in UI and look in the exported config.

Comment: You wrote "put this in the now empty visibility array" what do you mean by word "this"? You missed smth?

Comment: I add an example for a path visibility condition.

Comment: I was trying it but something went wrong. My block was created but it didn't attached to region. What I need to place at 'id' field instead of 'block_machine_name' ? I was trying to put there name of my block but seems it improperly.

Comment: You can use any machine name, as long as you use the allowed characters, which is alphanumeric + underscores. (For debugging it might be helpful if you place a block in UI, export the config and compare the result, what is different to the block you placed programmatically.)