# How to create custom block plugin for webform in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, blocks, webforms, plugins

I need to create custom blocks for every new webform. When User will create a webform, module should create a custom webform block.E.G. 'webform-1' becomes 'webform-1-block'. The resulting block must be of type 'webform_block' and reference the newly created webform.

How should I achieve this functionality? Any reference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need custom block? .By Default, Webform block will be created once the webform is created. Check in block layout -> place block of any region. You can find the webform block

Comment: I need to give only that webform region blocks to access the users. Right now, they can access all the blocks and regions under structure/block. So, I am thinking like create custom block and place into the specific region via a module. So the user can directly access via the page. Maybe I am thinking very complicated. Is any alternate solution to place webform block directly save into specific region?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251143/create-a-custom-block-programmatically-and-specify-region-and-pages-on-which-cre for how to place a block. In your case the plugin is `webform_block` and you have to provide the `webform_id` of the newly created webform in settings.